# Plant identification please. Volunteer shrub growing in yard in Sedona, AZ

Tags: identification, shrubs

[image]

This plant is growing in our yard and appeared as a volunteer. Looking to identify the shrub. Currently about two feet tall and splaying outwards with paired leaves.

Comment: Looks like Forsythia?

Answer (score 1):

As Yosef said, that looks like a [forsythia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsythia) to me.  I don't know the specific species which would tell you how large and how upright / arcing it intends to grow.

Forsythia grow quickly and are tough plants with lovely yellow flowers.  The flowers show up in the early spring on last year's new growth, so you need to keep some canes year-to-year if you want to see the flowers.  People will often trim their forsythia as soon as it finishes flowering so they can enjoy the flowers and give the plant the opportunity to grow new canes for flowers next spring.

Some folks prune forsythia as a hedge, although this can make keeping the flowers a challenge.

[image: A squared off hedge of forsythia, covered in yellow blooms]

Another pruning approach is to thin out / completely remove approximately 1/3 of the canes near the ground every year and otherwise let it do its thing.

[image: A forsythia with tall, arcing canes of yellow flowers]

A final approach is to just step back and admire the miracle of life.  This requires the most space.

[image: A very large patch of forsythia]